# Proximal-type support function properties - nonnegative & strongly convex (proof)

Tags: convex-analysis, convex-optimization, duality-theorems, subgradient

I am reading the paper of Prof. Yurii Nesterov:
`Primal-dual subgradient methods for convex problems`

The following part confuses me:

$\\$

$\\$

1. ${\color{red}{E}}\ $ ${\color{red}{\text{is a finite-dimensional real vector space.}}}$
2. ${\color{red}{d(x)}}\ $ ${\color{red}{\text{is strongly convex with a convexity parameter}\ \  \sigma \ \ \text{on}\ \ Q}}$
3. ${\color{red}{d(x_0)=0}}\ $, which is the minimal point.

[image]

My question is the last sentence. The first function is like the dual norm; since dual norm is a norm, which is nonnegative.

> How to show the second function is nonnegative? and also strongly convex with a convexity parameter $\sigma \beta$?

Note: The second question comes from his another paper with part of it:

[image]

Comment: Unless there is some relationship between $d$ and $x_0$, you cannot be sure that $V_\beta(s)$ is non negative. Note that $V_\beta(s) = \max_x (\langle s, x \rangle -\beta d(x)) - \langle s, x_0 \rangle$, hence for an appropriate (inappropriate!) choice of $x_0$, it must be negative.

Comment: I think so... the paper does not provide detailed about this.

Comment: I suspect that $x_0$ is a minimiser of $d$ and that $d(x_0) = 0$. Just having $d(x_0) = 0$ makes $V_\beta$ non negative.

Comment: @copper.hat Yes, $d(x_0)=0$, which is the minimal; if this holds, does my problem make sense?

Comment: I think so. ${}{}{}$

Comment: @copper.hat But $\beta d(x)$ could be very large; how to guarantee that $V_{\beta}(s)$ is nonnegative?

Comment: Evaluate the inner part at $x=x_0$, this is zero, hence the $\max$ must be non negative.

Comment: I understand; thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit: @copper.hat pointed out there's a much simpler solution.  Just note that 
\begin{align*}
V_\beta(s) = \max_x \, \langle s, x - x_0 \rangle - \beta d(x) \geq \langle s, x_0 - x_0 \rangle - \beta d(x_0) = 0.
\end{align*}

Previous answer:

I'll assume that $\beta = 1$ for simplicity.  Then
$V_\beta(s) = -\langle s, x_0 \rangle + d^*(s)$.
By the Fenchel inequality,
$\langle s, x_0 \rangle \leq d(x_0) + d^*(s)$.
Assuming that $d(x_0) = 0$, we see that
$0 \leq - \langle x, x_0 \rangle + d^*(s)$.
So $V_\beta(s) \geq 0$.

Comment: I get it; thanks!

Comment: If $d(x_0) = 0$ the non negativity follows without any duality...